# Slideshow looping, but selecting button causes speed up

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a JS slideshow. The looping through of it appears to work and goes back to the start. If I allow the autoTimer to run it also appears to loop with no fault.

My issue is when I choose a button to advance. It is speeding up or causing a double jump in `count`. I'm pretty sure I am using setTimeout incorrectly here but I'm struggling to see how to adapt what I have to use it correctly.

Any input is appreciated

```js
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var leftBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-left');
var rightBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-right');
var count = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  //clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
  for(var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
    sliders[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  sliderTimer();
}

function startSlide() {
  reset();
  // Access the first image
  sliders[0].classList.add('active');
  
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  // Add class to previous slide count minus 1
  sliders[count - 1].classList.add('active');
  // Then take 1 from count
  count--;
}

// Show next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliders[count + 1].classList.add('active');
  count++;
}
// Left arrow click
leftBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Check if it is at 0
  if(count === 0) {
    // Set count the total number of slides
    // The following function will handle the process of getting the last item
    count = sliders.length;
  }
  
  slideLeft();
})

// Right arrow click
rightBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Check if count is equal to sliders length - Last one
  if(count === sliders.length - 1) {
    // Go back to the first image
    count = -1;
  }
  
  slideRight();
})

function sliderTimer() {
  if(count === sliders.length - 1) {
    count = -1;
  }
  setTimeout(slideRight, 3000);
}

startSlide();
```

```css
.slider {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
 }
.slide {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}
    
.slide-1 {
  background: red;
}
  
.slide-2 {
  background: blue;
}
  
.slide-3 {
  background: green;
}
  
.slide-4 {
  background: orange;
}
    
.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}


.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}
  
.btn-left {
  left: 0;

}
  
.btn-right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide slide-1 active"></div>
  <div class="slide slide-2"></div>
  <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
  <div class="slide slide-4"></div>
  <button class="btn btn-left">Left</button>
  <button class="btn btn-right">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you manually trigger the slide buttons you aren't cancelling the previous timeout. What happens is:

- First timeout renders the first slide
- You manually change to the second slide after 1s
- Second slide is rendered and a second timeout is triggered
- After the remaining 2s, the first timeout resolves and changes the slide
- Third slide is rendered and a third timeout is triggered.
- Second timeout is resolved after the remaining 1s and changes the slide again.
- ... and so on.

To avoid this, when you manually change the slide you need to check if there's an existing timeout running and cancel it before starting another one.

```
// Create a variable holding the current timer
let currentTimer;

// Store the latest timeout reference
function sliderTimer() {
  if(count === sliders.length - 1) {
    count = -1;
  }
  currentTimer = setTimeout(slideRight, 3000);
}

// Cancel the current timer before starting one
rightBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Check if count is equal to sliders length - Last one
  if(count === sliders.length - 1) {
    // Go back to the first image
    count = -1;
  }
  if (currentTimer) {
    clearTimeout(currentTimer);
  }
  slideRight();
})

// You can extract this logic to an external function and reuse it when needed.
function cancelPrevTimer() {
  if (currentTimer) {
    clearTimeout(currentTimer);
  }
}
```